# Boolean basis complete?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

Check, whether boolean basis consisting of $\{\lor, \rightarrow \}$ is complete one?

Comment: Yes it is ... and if you search this site you'll probably find a proof why.

Comment: @Bram28 already tried, with no result unfortunately..

Comment: Moreover, from what is stated here I may come to conclusion that it actually isn't complete one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2329665/show-that-neg-p-cannot-be-written-in-terms-of-the-set-land-rightarrow. Or am I wrong?

Comment: My bad!  I read the $\to$ as a $\neg$. Wow, the power of constructive perception!

Comment: @Bram28 Oh, than everything is ok :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not complete. In particular, you can't construct $\neg$, since:

$$\mathrm{T}\lor\mathrm{T} = \mathrm{T} \rightarrow \mathrm{T} = \mathrm{T}$$

So there is no way of combining $\lor$ and $\rightarrow$ that will turn $\mathrm{T}$ into $\mathrm{F}$. This is the same reason $\left(\land,\rightarrow\right)$ is incomplete, as shown in the question you linked to.